# How to share authentication between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WEB API applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building an AngularJS MVC application, I need some guidance in terms of authentication. I am thinking of building the Authentication using the MVC authentication pipeline. AngularJS code will reside in the MVC application and the root SPA view would be a Razor cshtml. Here is my scenario -

- Login page will call a Authenticate API that would return a token
- AngularJS has the logic to get the bearer and pass to each of the API requests
- There will be multiple ASP.NET WebAPI projects that will be hosted as subdomains.
- I also need to call complex dynamic razor templates, this would need the authentication for the MVC controller that will return the razor views. Since MVC follows cookie based authentication, the token gives a 401 status code. How would this work wherein the authentication is shared between MVC and WEB API apps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to get your token from the API project, not the MVC in order to be able to securely call the API.

If you want to share identities across both the API and MVC projects, have them use the same database.

When getting the token from the API, you can get the identity details of the current user from your MVC application. At least, that is how I have done it in the past.

I blogged something along these lines here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2015/03/25/securing-and-working-securely-with-web-api.aspx however this does not cover the step of using the creds from your MVC login and passing that to the API to get the token.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Martin - I did not understand this part - "When getting the token from the API, you can get the identity details of the current user from your MVC application. At least, that is how I have done it in the past.". How would you get the identity from a MVC application hosted separately? I did find an article which seems promising - http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/ the only unknown I need to figure out is how I can authenticate the MVC controllers using the Authorization API.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure actually. The project I was thinking of had a single user for api access and the creds were hard coded. I'll look into this and post back if I find anything